# Hybridauth not working fine when rule configured with domain and sub-domain page

Tags: rules, authentication-authorization

I have configured Hybridauth social media module for my drupal. I have one main domain and sub-domain configured with my website. I have configured some rule for redirecting to home page with some conditions.

With that, For login, I have configured hybridauth for google and Facebook. In both the login process, The behavior is same, Once i enter credentials of facebook or google account, It shows me Closing.... message, If i remove Url parameter, It shows me logged in page of my drupal site.

Please help me to solve out this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Means login is working or not? which rule you have configured for redirecting?

Comment: Login is working very well. But When i am trying to logging in using Facebook or Gmail, It shows me message on white screen "Closing....." . And when i remove url parameters except my site url, it shows me logged in with Facebook or gmail.

Comment: what you have set in redirect path in configuration of hybridauth >> other settings >> Redirect after login?

Comment: No. No. I didn't set that. It is blank only. But i have set path using rules.

Comment: Try using [HTTP_REFERER] with  redirect after login.

Comment: I did, But it is default one provided by hybridauth. So i won't work in my case.